# I want to place a JApplet within a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, japplet, html

as the title says, I want to place a JApplet within a JPanel, because I'm making a plugin that is supposed to show a biological diagram. The Applet itself has already been written and I've also already made a HTML tag, which also works in a browser.
However,  I don't know how to get the applet to run within the JPanel

HTML tag:

```
<applet name="Spectrum_a" code="org/openscience/nmrshiftdb/spectrumapplet/SpectrumViewNoRenderer.class"
                codebase="/home/rianne/workspace/org.pathvisio.MetaboliteInfo/lib/"
                archive="spectrumapplet-bin-1.1.jar" width="450" height="350">
                    <param name="spectrum" value="197.74d;0.0;1|143.55;0.0;0|27.36;0.0;2t|">
                    <param name="realisticLines" value="true">
                    <param name="showCoupling" value="true">
                    <param name="hideNavigation" value="false">
                    <param name="autoIntensity" value="false">
                    <param name="solvent" value="CDCL3">
            </applet>
```

Hope someone can help me:)

Comment: The `<applet>` tag is not supported by Java's [`HTMLEditorKit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html).

Comment: Won't work, and it shouldn't (Applets are applications which run in their own JVM, not reusable UI components). If you wrote the applet, it should be easy enough to just retrieve the content pane of your applet and place that in the JPanel. You can not (or will ever be able to) run an applet from a JEditorPane.

Comment: @sarcan, you're wrong about the “their own JVM” part. In my experience, multiple applets in the same browser instance are run using the same JVM instance. Not sure if that is *always* the case, but I *am* sure that it *does* happen. So I don't think there is anything in the specs that guarantees an exclusive JVM to an applet.

Comment: You are correct, I should have said 'their own isolated area of the JVM'. However, considering the OP's problem, one can just as well think of an applet as a separate, autonomous process in contrast to a component you'd add to a panel.

Comment: @sarcan *"You can not (or will ever be able to) run an applet from a JEditorPane."* Perhaps not an 'out of the box' `JEditorPane`, but it is possible to change JEP (or rather the editor kit) so it will load applets.  [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/) is an example.

Answer (score 4):

To embed an applet into a Java application, I'd advise against using HTML. Instead, treat the [applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) as a simple [component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html), and try to behave like a browser plugin towards the applet. In particular, make sure to [set a stub](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#setStub%28java.applet.AppletStub%29) and call the [`init`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#init%28%29) and [`start`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#start%28%29) methods appropriately. It is that [stub](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletStub.html) which [provides parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletStub.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to the applet, so by implementing the [`getParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletStub.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) method appropriately, you can pass whatever parameters you desire.

You might have to create a separate [class loader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) for the jar of the plugin, and instantiate the plugin class through that class loader. If your environment doesn't allow your plugin the creation of new class loaders, then you should list the applet jar as a dependency of your plugin, so that its classes are available in the same class path your plugin uses. Doing so might be the easier route even if you're allowed custom class loaders, so choose whatever approach you prefer.

Comment: That makes, but how can I implement the parameters that I need?

Comment: @RianneFijten, added details about parameters to my answer.